# cannot draw a line with svg.js (javascript)

Tags: svg.js

```
const demo = document.getElementById('demo');
let draw = SVG().addTo('#demo').size('100%', '100%');
let line = draw.line(0, 0, 100, 150).stroke({ width: 1});
```

(SVG version 3.1.1, javascript)

The above codes yield nothing on the browser with no error, although I sucsessed with
draw.rect(), draw.circle() and draw.ellipse(). There must be some flaw somewhere because
I believe that theabove codes are correct. I hope that someone can help throw some light
on the issue, please. A lot of thanks to you.
T. Arayametee
Sep 22, 2021

Comment: Try adding a stroke color as well. Also take a look into your dev tools (f12). They are your friends and you can check what's generated

Comment: @Fuzzyma, you 're quite right! Thank you very much for your attention and help.         T. arayametee Sep 23, 2021